# Best method for creating a universal extention/plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to create an extension for the leading browsers (firefox, safari and ie).
Its rather simple, and I'm looking for the most efficient way to go about this.

I need to get the hostname of the current site the user is on, and if it matches a certain parameter(eg, mysite.org), I'll need to append to the link some extra data and refresh to the new link.

What is the simplest way to go about this?
(I don't want to go in the direction of a bookmarklet - since this would require the user to click. I'd like this to happen automatically)

sort of something like this:

```
if(window.location.hostname == 'mysite.org')
{
     location.replace(document.location.href + '/&mystuff=xyz');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler

Comment: That appears to be Firefox-specific. Am I missing something that would allow you to create an IE or Safari extension as well?